# How do I prevent objects in a collection at the same position from sticking together?

Tags: collections, origin

[image]I'm not sure if this is a bug, or something else.

I have a number of different objects, that are all placed in the same collection, and whose origins are all at 0,0,0.

For some reason, this makes it so when I try to move, or scale, or rotate them, they all do it.

I want only one of these objects to do so. What should I do about this?

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you have *Proportional editing* turned on? Please add a screenshot of your viewport.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be about right. Here, I'll throw a picture in of what it looked like.

Comment: Hey :). So, have you solved it or is it stil a problem? Because *Proportional editing* is off in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that solved it.